# Add a button on/outside/top of recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using recyclerview to show data. i want a button on top of layout so user can filter data. I want that user scroll on recyclerview button should be gone with scroll.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/djPhotos"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="satlaa.mysql_test.DJPhotos">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Text" />
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recylcerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

now button is sticked to top of the layout.

I tried scrollview but it makes recyclerview scrolling very slowly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U should try Coordinator Layout as below

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                app:elevation="@dimen/dp_0"
                >
                <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                    >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                        >
                        <Button
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:overScrollMode="never"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:splitMotionEvents="false"
                app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                app:offset="@{@dimen/dp_0}"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: <string name="appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" translatable="false">android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior</string>

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code: -

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    if (dy > 0 && mButton.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        mButton.hide();
    } else if (dy < 0 && mButton.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
        mButton.show();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: It's Not working . and i used mButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Answer (score 1):

Create two layouts. One for your other views and one for the button. Then in your adapter declare two global variable of int.

```
private static final int TYPE_BUTTON = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
```

Inside your `onCreateViewHolder` check for the appropriate layout to return.

```
 @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
            //inflate other items layout and pass it to view holder.
            //replace the null with your instance
            return new ItemViewHolder(null);
        } else if (viewType == TYPE_BUTTON) {
            //inflate button items layout and pass it to view holder.
            //replace the null with your view instance
            return new ButtonViewHolder(null);
        }
    }
```

Create two viewholders. One for button and other one for other list. For example:

> ButtonViewHolder

```
public class ButtonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

...
}
```

> ItemViewHolder

```
public class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

...
}
```

In your `getViewType()`, return button when its first position, else return other items. The function should look like the code below:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position ==0)
        return TYPE_BUTTON;

    return TYPE_ITEM;
}
```

Add 1 to the length of the items and return it in your adapter's `getItemCount()`.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.length + 1;
}
```

Check before binding to your viewholders. Like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof ItemViewHolder) {
        //Minus onString dataItem = getItem(position-1);
        //cast holder to ItemViewHolder and set data
    } else if (holder instanceof ButtonViewHolder) {
        //cast holder to ButtonViewHolder and set data for header.
    }
}
```

*Note:* minus `1` from every data you're trying to populate in your `onBindViewHolder` method where holder is instance of `ItemViewHolder`. 
Lemme know if you run into any problem, and always remember to post your log.